# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Tag')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I installed one library into React project with NPM.
The comand was `npm i react-modal-video` after i installed and started local server
React crashed with message `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Tag')`
[image]

I made a git stash for project in order to stash all changes, but it didn't help.
Even another project doesn't start anymore.

It looks like something went wrong with node modules.
But i cannot understand what to do with them i already uninstalled that library and made `npm install`.
Does anyone had sometging like this before ?